# Unable to convert UTF-8 text from NSDictionary in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsdictionary, nsdata, json

Im using `foursquare API` to get some locations around me, but when the name of that place wasn't in english, the name will be like follows:

```
name = "\U0645\U0633\U062c\U062f \U0627\U0644\U0633\U064a\U062f\U0629 \U0639\U0627\U0626\U0634\U0629 | Aisha Mosque";
```

i tried to convert the `response` to a UTF-8 but nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)setUpLocations{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.foursquare...."];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response: %@",[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"groups"]valueForKey:@"items"]);
}
```

And the log result is:

> ```
>       contact =                     {
>                 };
>                 id = 51712507498ec4e8c5ae9f48;
>                 likes =                     {
>                     count = 0;
>                     groups =                         (
>                     );
>                 };
>                 location =                     {
>                     address = Abdoun;
>                     cc = JO;
>                     city = Amman;
>                     country = Jordan;
>                     distance = 3819;
>                     lat = "31.95406043797281";
>                     lng = "35.88095228186612";
>                 };
>                 name = "\U0645\U0633\U062c\U062f \U0627\U0644\U0633\U064a\U062f\U0629 \U0639\U0627\U0626\U0634\U0629 | Aisha Mosque";
>                 restricted = 1;
>                 stats =                     {
>                     checkinsCount = 43;
>                     tipCount = 2;
>                     usersCount = 23;
>                 };
>                 verified = 0;
>             },
> ```

Any Suggestions ??

**EDIT:**
here is how i extract the data from the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"groups"]valueForKey:@"items"] copy];

namesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self removeWhiteSpaces:[dic valueForKey:@"name"]]];

-(NSArray *)removeWhiteSpaces:(NSDictionary *)dic{

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dic];
NSString *str2 = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSString *secondString = [str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];
NSString *thirdString = [secondString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
NSString *forthString = [thirdString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
NSString *fifthString = [forthString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSArray *items = [fifthString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


return items;



}
```

And in the `UITableView`:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@ ",[namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
```

**Update**

After trying @Martin R answer i got the same results:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[[[json objectForKey:@"response"]objectForKey:@"groups"]valueForKey:@"items"] copy];
NSString *value =[dic valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@", value);
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];;
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

and here is an image of the result[image: UILabel with the result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem.

NSLog() calls the `description` method of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`, and that prints all non-ASCII characters as `\Unnnn` escape sequence.

If you extract the string values from the dictionary and print that you will see
that everything is correct.

Simple example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"currency": @"€" };

NSLog(@"%@", dict);
// Output: { currency = "\U20ac"; }

NSString *value = dict[@"currency"];
NSLog(@"%@", value);
// Output: €
```

---

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to be in your `removeWhiteSpaces:` method, because

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dic];
```

already uses the `description` method to convert the dictionary to a string,
and the following `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` calls are a (sorry!) very bad
method to fix that.

You should access the dictionary keys with `objectForKey` instead, or enumerate
the dictionary with `for (NSString *key in dic) { ... }` and build the desired
array.

---

**UPDATE 2:** From the JSON data (posted in chat discussion) it seem that you just need

```
NSArray *itemsArray = json[@"response"][@"groups"][0][@"items]; 
NSArray *namesArray = [itemsArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Note that "groups" is an *array* with one element.

Comment: Not just printing it, also i had put it in a UITableView cell, and had the same result, Please Advice.

Comment: @Mutawe: Then you have not extracted the string value correctly. Perhaps you use `stringWithFormat` with a dictionary argument to set the cell's text?

Comment: The result \U0645\U0633.... is also came before calling removeWhiteSpaces: method, i tried your answer, See the update.

Comment: @Mutawe: Check the class of `dic` and `value` in the debugger. Is `dic` really a dictionary or is it an array? Could it be that `value` is in fact an array? - Note that `valueForKey` applied to an array returns an array!

Comment: if i tried to use objectForKey instead of calueForKey i got an error:-[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9939250

Comment: @Mutawe: It really depends on the JSON structure. Please try to *understand* what I am explaining. You have to inspect the JSON response and all your variables: Is it a dictionary, is it an array? And then apply the appropriate methods.

Comment: This is the first time i parse an JSON object, so im sorry for not understanding your points, Sorry for waisting your time with me .

Comment: @Mutawe: Can you upload the *complete* JSON response somewhere, and provide a download link? It is difficult to help without seeing the complete structure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37156/discussion-between-mutawe-and-martin-r)

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly :
NSArray *itemsArray = json[@"response"][@"groups"][0][@"items]; 
NSArray *namesArray = [itemsArray valueForKey:@"name"];
please update your answer to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one..

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]
```